# Cannot get website to be consistently centered on different devices, content seems to lean left

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, containers, centering

I am helping someone with their website, but running off of self-taught experience/have just taken over the work of another coder. When handed the site, it was in worse shape on mobile (sooooo much dead space) which I have seemed to fix, but this centering problem I have not been able to handle yet.

I am using Wordpress and was messing around with the CSS to make the text more consistent, and there are lots of blank spots in the code.

Code:

```css
    .logged-in header .navbar-default {
        top: 0px;
    }
    
    .toppa img:hover {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }
    
    .feeder { 
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
    
    .bio {
        padding-left: 8%;
        padding-right: 8%;
    }
    .bio h3 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    .lillogo {
        max-height: 35px;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 90%;
    }
    .lillogox {
        max-height: 20px;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 90%;
    }
    
    .lillogo2 {
        max-height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 90%;
    }
    
    .buttonup {
        padding: 12px;
        background-color: #efe4f1;
        border-radius: 20px;
        color: #000000;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
    
    .buttonup:hover {
        padding: 12px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        border-radius: 20px;
        color: #000000;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
    .brander   {
        font-weight: 800;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .entry-meta {
        display: none;
    }
    .transformer {
        max-width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-style: italicize;
        font-size: 1.6em;
    }
    
    .row.CC {
        padding-left: 15%;
        padding-right: 15%;
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    
    .bloxx {
        background: url('http://chrisrosenthaldesign.com/demos/wilyfoxx/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/bloxxbax-1.jpg');
    }
    .page-id-79 .CC p {
     text-align: justify;
      text-justify: inter-word;}
    
    .hometexter {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    .aligncenter {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    
    .page-id-194 h1 {
        font-weight: 800;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    .starter {
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    
    
    .page-id-194 .starter {
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    .starter img {
        height: auto !important;
        max-height: 80px;
        
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .page-id-194 .starter h2 {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
     .centaur  {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    .shrankit {
        padding-left: 20%;
        padding-right: 20%;
    }
    .ringer {
        max-width: 90px;
    }
    .centaurer  {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        margin-top: 20px !important;
        margin-bottom: 20px !important;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    
    .page-id-97 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .highlighter {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 1.8em;
    }
    .sb_instagram_header, .sbi_load_btn {
        display: none !important;
    }
    body.mob-menu-overlay, body.mob-menu-slideout, body.mob-menu-slideout-over, body.mob-menu-slideout-top {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    
    hr {
        width: 100%;
        height:1vh;
        color: #d4bce4;
    }
    
    .page-id-93 .rowtwo h2,
    .page-id-79 .rowtwo h2,
    .rowthree h2,
    .rowfour h2 {
        text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    h4 {
        border-bottom: 0px;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 100% ;
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    }
    
    .spanner h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .page-id-103 .spanner h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .spanner  {
        line-height: 1.8em !important;
    text-align: center;
        background-color: #efe4f1;
       color: #000000;
    PADDING: 20PX;
    font-weight: 800;
     width: 100vw;
         position: relative;
         margin-left: -50vw;
         left: 50%;
    }
    
    
    .logos  {
        border-top: 20px solid #efe4f1;
        border-bottom: 20px solid #efe4f1;
      margin-top: 50px;    
      margin-bottom: 220px;    
    
    }
    .page-id-97 .spanner h2 {
        line-height: 1.8em !important;
    text-align: left;
    }
    
    .page-id-97 .rowtwo h2 {
        line-height: 1.8em !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 800;}
    
    
    
    .page-id-97 .centaur  {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        text-align:  center !important;
    }
    
    h3 {
        width: 100% ;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    
    .page-id-103 h3 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .page-id-103 .rowtwo {
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .page-id-103 .subb h3 {
        text-align: center !important;
        margin-top: 46px !important;
    }
    .page-id-194 .rowtwo h2 {
        text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        margin-top: 30px !important;
        margin-bottom: 40px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    header .logo-tag img{
    max-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    width: auto;
    }
    
    header .logo-tag {
    float: left !important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 9;
    }
    .navbar-nav > ul {
        list-style: none !important;
    }
    
    
    .subb img {
        width: 66%;
        padding-top: 32px;
    }
    
    .subbbb img {
        width: 100%;
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
    
    
    .subbbb h3 { 
     margin-top: -6px;   
    }
    
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: left;
        height: 100px;
        display: inline !important;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav  {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    #mega-menu-wrap-primary #mega-menu-primary {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px !important;
            background-color: #000000;
    
    }
    
    .quoter, .citer {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .quoter {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    .citer {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .row .testimonial {
            border-bottom: 1px solid 000000 !important;
    
    }
    .socialbar {
        position: relative;
      text-align: center !important;
      margin: 0 auto !important;
            background-color: #000000;
            color: #efe4f1;
    z-index: 9;
    }
    .socialbar:hover {
    color: rgb(191, 176, 201);
    }
    
    .socialbar {
        text-align: right;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    
    #mobmenuleft .mob-expand-submenu, #mobmenuleft > .widgettitle, #mobmenuleft li a, #mobmenuleft li a:visited, #mobmenuleft .mobmenu-content h2, #mobmenuleft .mobmenu-content h3, .mobmenu-left-panel .mobmenu-display-name, .mobmenu-content .mobmenu-tabs-header li {
        font-family: Open sans;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        font-weight: inherit;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #e9ebf5;
    }
    
    .mobmenu-content #mobmenuleft > li > a:hover {
        background-color: rgb(191, 176, 201);
        color: #666;
    }
    
    
    .main-search,
    footer,
    .scroll-top-wrapper,
    .page-title {
        display: none !important;
    }
    
    .interior {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 1200px !important;
        margin: 0 auto !important;
    padding-left: 9% !important;
        padding-right: 9% !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
           max-width: 100% !important;
           margin: 0% auto !important;
        padding-left: 0% !important;
        padding-right: 0% !important;
        float:center;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    
    
    
    .spacer {
        margin-left: 0px !important;
        margin-right: 0px !important; 
        padding-top: 55px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .footers {
        background-color: #000000;
       padding-left: 0px !important;
        padding-right:  0px !important;
        padding-bottom:  0px !important;
        padding-top:  40px !important;
        text-align: center;
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    section.footers {
        background-color: #000000 !important;
    }
    .footers .col-sm-6,
    .footers .col-md-6,
    .footers .col-sm-3 {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
            flex: 0 0 100%;
    }
    
    
    .xer  {
     width: 60px;
     margin-top: 8px;
    }
    
    .mailer  {
     width: 40px;
     margin-top: 12px;
     margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    body {
        font: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
        color: #cccccc;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin-top: 55px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        float:center;
        width:100%;
    }
    
    
    #animated-example { 
      
    }
    
    .animated { 
        animation-duration: 1s; 
        animation-fill-mode: both; 
        animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
      animation-delay: 1s;
    width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20%;
        padding-right: 20%;
    } 
    
    .animated2 { 
        animation-duration: 1s; 
        animation-fill-mode: both; 
        animation-timing-function: ease-in; 
      animation-delay: 2s;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
        
    } 
    
    
    
    
    @keyframes fadeIn { 
        0% {opacity: 0;} 
        100% {opacity: 1;} 
    } 
    .fadeIn { 
        animation-name: fadeIn; 
    }
    
    
    
    .topprow {
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 12%;
        background-color: #000000;
        min-height: 10vh;
    }
    
    
    .statement {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-size:1.0vw;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin-top:-2.5vh;
        
        
    }
    
    .statement h2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 5.0vh;
        font-size:3.5vw;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-top:-4.5vh;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        
    }
    
    .rowone, .rowtwo, .rowthree, .rowfour {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    
    .rowtwo .row {
        padding-left: 9%;
        padding-right: 9%;
    }
    
    
    .page-id-93 .rowtwo .row {
        padding-left: 2%;
        padding-right: 2%;
    }
    
    
    .rowthree .col {
    }
    
    .rowtwo {
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 80px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .centerer h3 {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .subtext {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    .rowthree {
        padding: 20px;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-right: 5%;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .page-id-6 .rowthree {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    .page-id-97  h1 {
        text-align: center !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
        
    }
    
    
    
    a, a:visited {
        color: #efe4f1;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    a:hover {
        color: rgb(191, 176, 201);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    
    .buttoner {
        border: 1px solid rgb(220, 204, 232);
        padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
        color: rgb(220, 204, 232) !important;
    }
    
    
    .buttoner:hover {
        border: 1px solid rgb(191, 176, 201);
        color: rgb(191, 176, 201);
    }
    
    
    #sb_instagram .sbi_follow_btn a {
        background:  #C5BEE9;
        color: #000000;
        font-family: 'montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-weight:500;
        font-size:1.5vw;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        
    }
    #sb_instagram .sbi_follow_btn a:hover {
        background: rgb(191, 176, 201) !important;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    
    .blurb {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    
    .rowfour {
        text-align: center;
            background-color: #000000;
        padding: 40px;
    
    }
    
    .col {
        min-width: auto;
    }
    
    #mobmenuright li a, #mobmenuright li a:visited, #mobmenuright .mobmenu-content h2, #mobmenuright .mobmenu-content h3, .mobmenu-left-panel .mobmenu-display-name {
        font-family: Open Sans;
       
    }
    .object-fit_cover { 
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 1400px;
    }
    
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card-front {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
       font-size: 0.9em;
       line-height: 2.4em;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    
    
    .kcd,
    .lrh {
        display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-items: flex-start;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    .kcd.flip-card-back,
    .lrh.flip-card-back {
        padding: 0px !important;
    }
    .flip-card {
      background-color: transparent;
      height: 240px !important;
      perspective: 1000px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .flip-card-inner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .flip-card-front {
      background-color: #161616;
      color: #ffffff;
      border: 4px solid #bfb0c9;
    }
    
    .flip-card-front {
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    
        .flip-card-back { 
            font-weight: 800;
        }
        .AA .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #efe4f1;
      color: #161616;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      padding: 20px;
      line-height: 1.4em;
             padding: 10%;
    
        }
    .flip-card-back  {
    
        
    }
    
    .BB .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #efe4f1;
      color: #161616;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      padding: 10px;
     line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 30px;
        
    }
    
    .CC .flip-card-back {
       background-color: #efe4f1;
      color: #161616;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      padding: 10px;
     line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 30px;
        
    }
    
    
    .CCC .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #838383;
      color: white;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      padding: 40px;
     line-height: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 30px;
        
    }
    
    .page-id-93 {
        text-align: center !important;
    }
    .page-id-79 .testimonials {
        text-align: center !important;
        
    }
    
    
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card {
      width: 100%;
      height: 900px;
      perspective: 1000px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card-inner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 900px;
      text-align: center;
      transition: transform 0.6s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    
    .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      
    }
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card-back {
      background-color: #efe4f1;
      color: black;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .mob-retina-logo {
        height: 49px!important;
    }
    
    
    .socialbar {
        text-align: right;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    
    
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    
    
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .mob-retina-logo {
        height: 49px!important;
    }
    
    .col {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
        color: #cccccc;
        background-color: #f9f9fb;
        margin-top: 55px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        
    }
    header .logo-tag img{
    max-height: 45px;
    width: auto;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggle {
        position: fixed;
       right: 12px;
       top: 1px;
    
    }
    .navbar {
        min-height: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        position: fixed;
       right: 12px;
       top: 1px;
    
    }
    .navbar {
        min-height: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        
    }
    
    
    .socialbar {
        position: relative !important;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px !important;
    z-index: 9;
    }
    
    .socialbar {
        text-align: right;
        padding: 4px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card {
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 100%;
      height: 1000px;
      perspective: 1000px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .page-id-79 .flip-card-front {
       padding-top: 60px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    .flip-card-front {
        padding-top: 80px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin: 0px !important;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2.1em;
        text-align:center;
    }
    
    h2 {
        font-size: 1.8em;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        
    }
    
    h3 {
        font-size: 1.4em;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
    
    h4 {
        font-variant small-caps;
        text-align:center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        line-height:1em;
        font-size:2.2em;
        margin-top:-200px;
    }
    
    .page-id-97 .rowtwo h2 {
        font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 1.4em !important;
    }
    
    
    .rowtwo {
        padding: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .statement h2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        line-height: 1.6em;
        font-size: 2.4em;
        
    }
    
    
    
    }
```

```html
        <div="aligncenter"><div class="container-fluid topprow">
      <div class="row">
    <div id="animated-example" class="animated fadeIn toppa"><a href="#jump"><img src="http://www.wilyfoxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/wilyfoxxlogoreversed1a.png" alt="" width="max" height="max" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-167" /></a></div>
    &nbsp;
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <hr>
    <div class="container-fluid statement">
      <div class="row" >
    <h2><big><h1 style><bold>a modern agency</h1></big>
    for the people, the brands, and the institutions
    changing the world
    
    <img src="http://www.wilyfoxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/wilytopp.jpg" alt="" width="max" height="max" align="center" id="start"/></h2>
    
    
    
    <div class="container-fluid rowthree">
      
    
    
      <div class="row feeder">
    [instagram-feed]
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I'm going crazy and have been trying to solve this for multiple days!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you copied it wrong or maybe the error is in the source code.

The first div is written wrong, it should be `<div class="aligncenter">`
and not `<div=aligncenter>`.
also in the css you have `aligncenter` property which will be applied on that div when you fix that.

If the error is in the code try and fix that.